# How much hand sanitizer can be taken through airport security in the EU?

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage, eu, tsa

The US TSA [recently increased](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/hand-sanitizers) the amount of liquid hand sanitizer allowed through airport security to 12oz up from 3.4oz (the usual rule for liquids).

What about airport security in the EU?  Is there any sort of exemption to / relaxation of the usual rule for liquids which applies to hand sanitizer?

I hope a general answer for all the EU exists, but if it does not, I am specifically interested in France and Greece.

Answer (score 2):

The [IATA published an article](https://www.iata.org/contentassets/90f8038b0eea42069554b2f4530f49ea/covid-19-dangerous-goods-guidance.pdf) regarding hand sanitizer limits (emphasis mine, grammar & spelling corrected):

> The total net quantity of all such articles carried by each passenger or crew member under the provisions of 2.3.5.1  must not exceed 2 kg or 2 L and the net quantity of every single article must not exceed 0.5 kg or 0.5 L. Release valves on aerosols must be protected by a cap or other suitable means to prevent inadvertent release of the contents.
>
> **Alcohol-based hand sanitizers acceptable under the provisions of 2.3.5.1, however, it should be noted that where passengers or crew wish to have the hand-sanitizer in their carry-on baggage that the limit of 100 mL or equivalent per item for liquids and gels in accordance with the aviation security provisions applies**

Comment: So we don't have to put them in the same bag as the other liquids?